# Powerpoint 2010 - Keyboard shortcut to enable text wrapping

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I'm working quite a bit in Powerpoint 2010 and I very much need a shortcut-key to activate text wrapping for a chosen shape.

Is there a keyboard shortcut-key?

Answer (score 0):

Select the shape, then

<kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>Pg down</kbd>, <kbd>up arrow</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The keys separated by a comma are pressed after one another, the <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> is pressed simultaneously.

Comment: Thx teylen, that's a bit longer than I hoped for.  Isn't there a more direct shortkey?

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a **PowerPoint macro**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814734%28v=office.14%29.aspx) using the following code and [add it to the **Quick Access Toolbar**](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-add-an-excel-2010-macro-to-the-quick-access.html):

```
Sub ToggleShapeTextWrap()
    Dim oShp As Shape
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type <> ppSelectionShapes Then
        MsgBox "Please select some shapes!", vbExclamation, "Shape Selection"
    Else
        For Each oShp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
            If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
                oShp.TextFrame.WordWrap = Not oShp.TextFrame.WordWrap
            End If
        Next oShp
    End If
End Sub
```

Unlike other Office apps I don't think you can define custom keyboard shortcuts for PowerPoint macros without an add-in such as [this one](http://officeone.mvps.org/ppsctmgr/ppsctmgr.html), so adding a button for the macro to the QAT or Ribbon would be the best way to enable quick access.